# Exception throws There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I wanted to check user is valid or not.it gives me the exception,When user valid it's working without issue,But if user invalid there's some issue.

> Exception is : There is no row at position 0

Here is the part of the code,

```
 public bool CheckUserExistAndReporter(string user)
{
    int reporterDnnId = -1;
    SMSFunctionController mysms = new SMSFunctionController();
    DataSet uds = mysms.GetUsersUnitByUserName(user);

    reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);
    if (reporterDnnId > 0)
    {
        bool isValidUser = true;
        return isValidUser;
    }
    //else
    //{
        //bool isValidUser =false;
        //return isValidUser;
   // }
    return false;
}
```

Then i call thatone here.

```
                if (!CheckUserExistAndReporter(user))
                {
                    ErrorLog(messageIn);
                    msgOut = "ugyldig Bruker";//Invalid User.

                }
```

what is the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also the rows count before accessing userId in row[0] .

```
public bool CheckUserExistAndReporter(string user)
{
    bool isValidUser = false;

    SMSFunctionController mysms = new SMSFunctionController();
    DataSet uds = mysms.GetUsersUnitByUserName(user);

    if (uds != null && uds.Tables.Count > 0 && uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    { 
        // do further validation
        var reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);
        if (reporterDnnId > 0)
        {
           isValidUser = true;         
        }
    }
    return isValidUser;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading all answers I think this one is better than others , put following If in your code.

```
if(uds != null && uds.Tables.Count > 0 && uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method `mysms.GetUsersUnitByUserName(user)` is returning an empty table. Probably the criteria for the selection is not fulfilled that is why when you try to access it. You are getting the error. Its better if you can add a check before accessing the data row. Something like.

```
if(uds != null && uds.Tables.Count > 0 && uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
     reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);
```

Comment: if uds is null your code will throw null reference exception. if uds is not null but there is no table in uds your second part of the if will throw error.

Comment: in late case your first part of the if will also throw exception. Index out of bound exception.

Comment: @muhammadkashif, for a safe side, yes, it should be done like that. But the OP asked for the exception that there was no row. So My assumption was that his method is creating a new DataSet and returning an empty table. Otherwise he would have a NRE. Currently his error is `There is no row at position 0`.

Comment: When you suggest , always suggest the best thing. you have an option to edit your post. just do that.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);
```

You are accessing a row by index. If the user isn't valid, presumably there are no rows, thus the index is out of range.

If all you care about is a record being returned from the database, you could do something like:

```
bool isValid = uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
```

A more robust check would be:

```
bool isValid = false;
if( uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && (int)uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"] != default( int ) ){
    isValid = true;
}
```

Cleaned up a little:

```
var rows = uds.Tables[0].Rows;
bool isValid = rows.Count > 0 && (int)rows[0]["DnnUserID"] != default( int );
```

Or if you need the conversion (casting is cheaper and will work unless the value isn't an Int32):

```
var rows = uds.Tables[0].Rows;
bool isValid = rows.Count > 0 && Convert.ToInt32( rows[0]["DnnUserID"] ) != default( int );
```

Comment: yes.How can i show when user invalid ? It needs to go inside the If condition of the caller function

Comment: Updated my answer with a few examples.

Comment: in case uds is null or in case where uds does not contain any table your code will throw exception.

Comment: So what? there is significant difference between checking if an operation returns rows in response to a query and the operation failing to return an object. If the expected result is a table (empty or not) and null is returned, I *want* the exception.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
if(uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
  reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is on this line `reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]);`. You have to check `if (uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)` before continue process the code.

```
if (uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    reporterDnnId = Convert.ToInt32(uds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DnnUserID"]); 
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First find out weather dataset contain any record or not and then proceed

```
if (uds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    // retrieve id and return it
    }
    else
    {
    return something which indicates record not found
    }
```